# SQL 2000 Function - cant return a varchar

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working on some old SQL 2000.  I need a function that returns a string.  Thats about it.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tmp] ( @CurrentCheck VARCHAR(80) = '10161681' )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
    AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN CAST('fred' AS VARCHAR(2000));
    END
```

This gives an error message: 42000 - [SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to int.

Not sure where the int comes from.  Oddly if I put an int in place of 'fred' it works.  But what I need is to return a VARCHAR.

```
    RETURN 'fred'
```

Gives the same error.

```
    RETURN 314
```

Works, sadly this is not a varchar but an int.  is there something wrong with the RETURNS VARCHAR line?

Further, if I put in

```
    Declare @logid varchar(50);
    RETURN  @logid
```

it works, sends back a blank line

but

```
    Declare @logid varchar(50);
    SET @logid = 'fred'
    RETURN  @logid
```

once again causes it to fail with the same int error...

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can you show complete code that you run in SSMS or query analyser that produces this error?

Comment: Are you sure [dbo].[tmp] is a function, not a procedure? Procedures are limited in only being able to return an int.

Comment: lol.  ok - got it figured.  Navicat was running the functions as procedures.  thanks Green and Martin, between the two of you i figured it out.  just a bug in an older version of Navicat.